# can't log into ubuntu after rsync restore of home folder

Tags: login, 14.04, rsync

I have recently reinstalled ubuntu/lubuntu 14.04 onto my wife's Packard Bell Dot S netbook after an unsuccessful upgrade from 12.04. I followed this by restoring the home directory from a backup using rsync. I used the

> --archive

option which is supposed to keep permissions and ownership information. I can log onto my account but not hers. When I log on it immediately goes back to the login screen. I tried to change the ownership of all my wife's files in her home directory from my account but even this did not help. Why does this occur and how can I get to log into her profile. I must add that the install was successful as I could log into her account prior to the restore using rsync.
I followed the exact same process for the install and restore on another computer and there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is one file in particular to look at: `~/.Xauthority` in her home directory.

Note that its a hidden file.

Log in to your account, go to her home directory and `mv .Xauthority .old_Xauthority`.

Log out and have her log in.

`man xauth` to learn more.

Comment: Thanks. This does seem to be a problem. She does not seem to have an .Xauthority directory in her home. I checked that all other profiles I can log into have a .Xauthority. What to do now?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. The point of moving it is to force it to be recreated on login. Since its not being created how about making a blank `touch .Xauthority` in her ~ with 777 permissions.

Comment: I tried that. I also tried changing the ownership of the .Xauthority file to her profile and also didn't work.

Comment: I just noticed something strange. Her home folder was encrypted during install. When I try to `ls -la ../herfolder` it only has a few files and folders in. They are: _Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop_ _.Private_ _.ecryptfs_ _README.txt_ and _.Xauthority_. I also copied over the _.Xauthority_ file in the backup over again but it still won't allow me to log in.

Comment: The README.txt file says that
THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA.
....
From the command line, run:
ecryptfs-mount-private

Should I try and run this from my profile???

Comment: I managed to log in using `ctrl+alt+f1` purely in text mode. I tried to run the `ecryptfs-mount-private`. Unfortunately I have not yet written down the passphrase so won't allow me in. Is there any other way of getting logged in?

Comment: I have never used encryption with Ubuntu. You should edit your question to include this new information or maybe even open a new one. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a Fedora system, but the root cause may apply to Ubuntu or other Debian systems depending on their configuration.

After some analysis, I found a major possible cause: file contexts.
If you clone a home folder using rsync --archive, there are several things that do NOT get copied. Hard links, ACLs and XAttrs are mentioned in the help. File contexts are not copied either.
By default, all home folder entries are type user_home_t. Some hidden files like the .Xauthority have more restrictive types like xauth_home_t.
However, the copy created by rsync will most likely be to a non-home folder and thus all the copied files will be labeled to the unlabeled_t type.
This means that, depending on the protection level in your system, even if the owner is set correctly (which the --archive option does), the files may be locked because of the file context.

You can verify this easily with this command:
ls /home//* -Zd
This will show the file contexts.

Fixing the file context should be easy. Using root access, just use this command:
restorecon -vR

Hope this helps someone.