# Can't Log In As User After Using A Restore Script

Tags: command-line, backup, rsync, restore, 16.04

I used this [**script**](https://github.com/tsimonq2/backup/blob/master/restore.sh) to restore my files and installed packages (home folder not encrypted) after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.  But when I tried to log in as a user, graphically, it just took me back to the log in screen.  I can log on as a user via command-line from the log in screen.

As the solution to [can't log into ubuntu after rsync restore of home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450072/cant-log-into-ubuntu-after-rsync-restore-of-home-folder), says to remove the `~/.Xauthority` file from the home folder and create a new one, this didn't work for me.

Comment: Could you try going to tty1 and logging in? Then could you give the output of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you backup and restore, the permissions need to be identical, otherwise, you will not be able to log in. You could probably boot into recovery mode and do a recursive `chown` on your home directory. This should probably fix it.